# Failed to initiate p2p connection between raspberrypi4 and linux Laptop

Tags: wifi, pi-4, linux, p2p

currently, I am working on a P2P connection between Laptop and Rpi4
facing interface creation fail issue while using wpa_supplicant to create a connection between the laptop and Raspberry Pi 4B to establish a Wi-Fi Direct

But when I tried to connect Rpi4 and mobile it was getting connected and the connection is stable for 20 seconds, later it was getting disconnected.
Here I am attaching a snapshot of my problem

I hope for some help/solution regarding my problem